# Change jQuery hover() to click() on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple jQuery drop-down and it works with no problems. The issue I am having is on my responsive design it still keeps the hover effect which isn't working correctly on mobile. Is there anyway to cancel the hover once the hamburger icon `.menu` is clicked? The idea is to keep the `.subNav` hidden on mobile and once the user clicks the `.topNav li a` the `.sabNav` slides down. I couldn't attach the responsive design in the fiddle but you can probably get a good idea of what it's doing.

http://jsfiddle.net/9L3cE/1/

Answer (score 0):

This question is bigger than just what you're trying to accomplish. The real problem is determining this: What is mobile? In your case, you're using small screen size as a proxy for touch screen capability.

This might be an ok solution for now, but it's not a great long term solution. What if a tiny netbook comes to your site, and based on the responsive breakpoints you've set, it gets the "mobile" view based on its screen size, but it's a device without any actual touch capability?

Anyway, if you're using screen size as a proxy for touch capability, you can just go into your javacript and set a flag on the event that you want to use based on the window width you've determined as your "mobile" (touch) breakpoint. E.g. for a breakpoint at 600px:

```
var menuEvent = ($(window).width() < 600) ? 'hover' : 'click';
```

Then, when you want to bind your UI events, you would use:

```
$(element).bind(menuEvent, function() { ... });
```

Comment: BTW, if you're using a newer version of jQuery use .on() instead of .bind(). It's the preferred method for attaching event handlers now. .bind() is just an old habit for me I'm still shaking.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you should determine whether the device has `hover` or no. If it has `hover`, then generate your `html` so the result will be:

```
<body class="with-hover">
    <!-- HTML Structure -->
</body>
```

If it does not have a `hover`, you should have:

```
<body class="without-hover">
    <!-- HTML Structure -->
</body>
```

Now, define your `hover` event to be applicable specifically for the case when `hover` if possible:

```
$("body.width-hover").on("hover", yourSelector, function() {/*Hover code here*/});
```

Also, define your `click` event

```
$("body.without-hover").on("click", yourSelector, function() {/*Click event here*/});
```

Comment: I don't think this is a solution. Just about every browser out there has hover events. Even mobile browsers map those to touch actions (e.g. tap once to trigger the hover over state, tap out of container to trigger hover out).

Comment: You did not understand the answer then. We check whether the device has a hover event, not whether the browser has a hover event. This can be done in multiple ways, including checking the size of the screen as described in your post, but that is a different problem, therefore it is irrelevant to the question. We have to check whether hover is applicable. Logically, not technically. On an Android device hover is not applicable, even though it uses browsers which support the hover event.

Comment: Lajos: totally fair response. But I'm interested to learn how we can detect whether or not a *device* has hover capability within the browser environment. I can't say I've ever done that.

Comment: Good question! In fact, that is a very good question. Your solution is acceptable, described in your post, however, you can detect OS or user agent. See more here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6077/browser-and-os-detection-script and here http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/wiki/Mobile_Detect